# Does failing to load a remote javascript file stop javascript execution in any browsers?

Tags: javascript

I've got a stand alone script file that I want to load from a 3rd party server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//some_server/logger.js"></script>
```

There's a small chance the remote script won't be there sometimes (404), and I want to be sure that including this script doesn't affect how my app operates, since ***my app doesn't require the script to be loaded to work*** (it's an analytics tracker of sorts)

***Can I include this script safely without it blocking or causing javascript errors in my app that stops other javascript from running?***

I was thinking of adding the `async` and `defer` attributes to make the script load lazily. Is this enough? My app needs to work on IE8 and above.

Here's what I'm thinking right now:

```
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="//some_server/logger.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("I want this to always execute, no matter if the above script 404's or not!");
</script>
```

Comment: use async or defer attribs on the script tag to avoid stalling the page rendering.

Comment: that's my current thoughts on it, but will this cause any issues if the script isn't there sometimes (e.g. 404s) ?

Comment: If you have other js on the page that is dependent on the script I would suggest using the jquery .getscript function. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ Then put all the dependent code inside of the callback. All other code will run just fine if the script is not loaded.

Comment: no other code depends on the script... it's additional analytics that isn't required or used in any sense by the rest of the app...

Comment: http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/ explains  defer and async. They have nothing to do with 404s as far as I can see...

Comment: a 404 on a dynamically added script or hard coded script tag w/async attrib will not stall anything else on the page. without  the attribs, a slow server will pause rendering, but a fast 404 won't slow much down, it will just make an error in the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I include this script safely without it blocking or causing
> javascript errors in my app that stop other javascript from running?

## YES you can

A 404 does not halt execution of javascript in any way, only errors do.
As long as the server responds with a 404, and doesn't hang, the script not loading won't cause any noticeable delay.

This can be tested in different browsers by logging the time it takes to check a 404 or broken link.
Just the fact that the browser logs the time, shows that such scripts does not halt execution of javascript, the thread always continues on to the next script tag unless the parser encounters an error in a script, if the URL isn't found, no browser will throw an error, it just goes on as soon as the URL is not resolved.

```
<script>console.time('Test');</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.broken.url/file.js"></script>
<script>console.timeEnd('Test');</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujtj7n7o/1/)

Testing in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera shows that all browsers use less than 0.0002 seconds to resolve a broken link, and the time it takes to resolve a 404 depends on how fast the server responds, but for Google's servers it seems to consistently be less than 0.2 seconds in all browsers before the 404 status code is returned, and the browser keeps executing the next scripts.

Even adding up 20 scripts that all return a 404 takes generally less than half a second for the server to resolve and move on

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujtj7n7o/2/)

In other words, you can safely add any script that has a broken link or returns a 404, it won't break anything, and it won't hang the browser in any way, it only takes a few milliseconds for modern browser to determine that the script can't be loaded, and move on.

What you can't do, is include scripts that actually load, and contain fatal errors, as that will stop the entire thread, and any execution of scripts that comes after the error is encountered.

Comment: This is what I expect, but I'd love to see some sources for actual browser results, cross platform, etc... thanks
!

Comment: @BradParks - added a little more context to the answer, to try and explain the behaviour. How a browser handles scripts that can't be loaded is up to the vendor, and there is no standard for it, but this is something that happens quite often, scripts dissappear, servers go down etc. and all browsers handles such errors extremely quick and reliable without any issues.

Answer (score 4):

Define all functions you use (which are in //some_server/logger.js) as empty functions before loading the script and you'll have no exceptions even if you use them without the script being loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   functionInLogger = function() {
   };
   functionInLogger2 = function() {
   };
   ...
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//some_server/logger.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   functionInLogger(); 
   functionInLogger2();
   console.log("This will always work");
</script>
```

And when the script is loaded, it'll override the empty functions.

I could not find any popular browser that will stop execution upon a 404. And W3 standard only states this; ([W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html))

> When the user agent is required to execute a script block, it must run the following steps:
>
> ...
>
> If the load resulted in an error (for example a DNS error, or an HTTP 404 error)
> Executing the script block must just consist of firing a simple event named error at the element.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but the script doesn't expose any functions at all.... it's like google analytics, and isn't really used by my app but logs info about the current url and other browser data, pretty much. So it not loading won't stop my app's features from working, since my app doesn't depend on this file.

Comment: Then it'll never intervene with your code as long as you don't call it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can place that script on the bottom of the page (after all your important script), to make sure this will not block rendering of your page.

Or you can also load it after document ready, this method will not give extra load time when the script are not found. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="//some_server/logger.js"></script>');
});
```

or use $.getScript method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('//some_server/logger.js', function(data, textStatus) {
        /*optional stuff to do after getScript */ 
    });
});
```

** in example above I assume if you are using jQuery*

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition):
It allow developers to define dependencies that must load before a module is executed, so the module doesn't try to use outside code that isn't yet available.